# Angular 2 get first 5 items from subscribe

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, ionic2, observable

[image]
Hi anyone know how to get the first 5 items from the subscribe , currently it returns everything. I only need the first 5 object.

```
    Apac.map(res => res.text())
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.parseXML(data)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.xmlItemsApac = data;
                     console.log(this.xmlItemsApac)
                });
        });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the first 5 items from `subscribe`, because `subscribe` is returning an XML document, apparently...

...so you're parsing an XML document.

After it's parsed, you're getting an array.
Because you're getting an array, you can simply call slice on it.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].slice(0, 5); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing to do with subscribe, subscribe is just subscribing your event which was emitted. Whatever you emit, the subscriber will subscribe that event. In subscriber you can write a loop to have only first five objects and store them in to different array to use. Or use slice as mentioned above